# Any way to extract values from TDBGrid?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

```
if(TPoints->Filter == String(Lat1) + String(" < Latitude AND ")+
                  String("Latitude< ")+ String(Lat2) + String(" AND ")+
                  String(Lon2) + String("< Longitude AND ")+
                  String("Longitude < ") + String(Lon2));
else{
    ShowMessage("Invalid Boundries");
}
```

First time using data access and control components. 
TPoints is a TADOTable, results are listed in a TDBGrid. If possible I need to do more than just showing the filtered results (filtering code above) from database. How to go to a specific row or maybe cell and play with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move to a specific record, you have to set the `RecNo` property of `TADOTable`.

In a database, moving to a specific field of a record (AKA a cell) does not mean much, unless you want to edit the content of it. The `Edit()` method of `TADOTable` can put a record into edit mode, but I'm not sure how you can choose a cell programmatically. It also depends on your design. Normally, the user can start the edit mode by double-clicking on a cell, which takes care of everything automatically. But, if you want to change the data without the user typing it, a `TADOQuery` and `SQL` statement is a much better choice.

Be more specific about what you want to happen on the screen and the user's interaction. That way, we can help you better.

By the way, you don't extract data from the grid itself, you extract it from a DataSet (`TADOQuery` or `TADOTable`) that the grid is attached to.

Comment: I'm constraining a region by latitude and longitude by filtering, and showing the points that remain in the middle of boundary latitude and longitudes on a map. So I need the values in the fields, not to edit them.

Comment: @HasanKaraman You still have to read the values from `TADOTable`. You do this by `pTable->FieldByName(Field1Name)->As...` or `pTable->Fields->Fields[i]->As...`. Normally at the beginning your TADOTable is pointing to the 1st record. After you read the data from the record you can use `Next()` to move on to the next record. You have to do this while `Eof` is false. The grid is for display only. Read the data from TADOTable.

Comment: your comment answered the question, thanks. You may want to update the answer accordingly.